# Contact form not working

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I am pretty new to web programming and am trying to get a personal website up and running. I have a contact form which does not seem to execute anything. I have poured over the web looking for the error in my code, but I have hit a wall.

scripts in header

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://html5form.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.html5form-1.5-min.js"></script>
```

html5 form

```
<form action="message.php" method="post" id="message_form">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" title="Email address" maxlength="40" placeholder="Email Address" autocomplete="off" required />
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" title="Subject" maxlength="60" placeholder="Subject" autocomplete="off" required />
        <br />
        <textarea name="message" id="message" title="Message" cols="30" rows="5" maxlength="1000" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit" name="submit"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

script in body (linked)

```
$('#message_form').html5form({
    allBrowsers : true,
    responseDiv : '#response',
    messages: 'en',
    messages: 'es',
    method : 'GET',
    colorOn :'#0d85a5',
    colorOff :'#d2d2d2'
});
```

message.php

```
<?php
if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
$to = "rbblakeley@gmail.com";
$from = "r.blakeley@yahoo.com";
$subject = "test subject";
$message = "test message";

$body = "$from\n $message";

echo "Your message has been sent!";
mail($to, $subject, $body);
} else {
echo "Rapscallions! Please try again.";
}
?>
```

testing on a local MAMP server and uploading to my remote host (bluehost), nothing happens when I hit 'send' except the forms resets to placeholder values. help.

Comment: locally its no surprise unless you happen to be running a mail server. best way to test is to remove everything you don't need, you could just run the mail() function and hard code the values to make sure that works before  moving on.

Comment: @Dragon so are you saying it looks right, but I need to strip it down to start trouble shooting?

Comment: on S.O someone will  usually give you the exact answer but learning to trouble shoot your self will go a a long way.

Comment: @dagon tried hard coding the php variables and gave the submit input a name...still stuck in the same place.

Comment: do you just run the mail() function with nothing else - if this fails ask your host.

Comment: Solution:

Be sure to have a proper php.ini file saved in your website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to give your submit button a name

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send" id="submit"/>
```

A better way to do this might be instead of

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
```

Use:

```
if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
```

This method doesn't check for a specific variable. It checks the request method and if it's POST then the form was submitted.

Comment: Tried your advice, but no change. Still no error code, thank you message or email sending.

Comment: You had proper advice, but i was missing a php.ini file in my website. This and that got everything working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` contains an associative array of keys (from the `name` on the inputs) and their respective values.

Since no input has `name='submit'`, your `if` statement will always be false.

At any rate, you'll probably want to use something like this (it is a better check to see if things are correct):

```
if(empty($_POST['subject']) || empty($_POST['email'] || empty($_POST['message'])){
    echo "Rapscallions! Please try again.";
} else {
    // do your thing
}
```